# How to do an LDAP search on a muli value Attribute

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to do a LDAP Search on a multivalue attribute ACL using PHP. But when I try to set a filter on ACL `$filter="(ACL=*$cn*)"` where `$cn = prnman03` there are no results returned.

```
ACL                - 16#entry#cn=prnman03,ou=ipp,ou=services,o=uct#[Entry Rights]
                     3#entry#[Root]#iPrintPrinterIPPURI
                     8#entry#ou=backup,ou=ipp,ou=services,o=uct#iPrintPrinterUserRole
                     8#entry#ou=ippl,ou=ipp,ou=services,o=uct#iPrintPrinterUserRole
                     8#entry#ou=ipp,ou=services,o=uct#iPrintPrinterUserRole

cn                 -  IPP00005
iPrintPrinterIPPURI- ipp://srvnbsidw001.uct.ac.za/ipp/IPP00005
```

Comment: I think you should provide more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the attribute values matches the filter, then the entry will be considered to be returned (as long as permissions allow).
But remember that LDAP Filters are resolving in True, False, Undefined. Undefined means that there was no way to apply the filter and get a result. If there is no substring matching rule defined for the ACL attribute, then matching a substring filter will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing this on an ACL for eDirectory, I do not think you will find and values that work for substrings. Even though their [documentation](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ndslib/schm_enu/data/sdk5638.html) say there are some conditions where matching will work, I have not be able to find or perform any such matches.